# Formal name for polygon with hole

Tags: geometry, terminology, polygons

Is there a formal name for an irregular polygon that has 1 or more holes or cutouts in it? I've heard it refered to as a "swiss cheese polygon" or a "Donut polygon". Is this even strictly a polygon?

Comment: It is not a polygon, since by definition, a polygon is a plane figure bounded by a closed curve.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard name. *Polygon with holes* (958 hits on Google Books) is the usual term; rarer terms include *donut/doughnut polygon* (70 hits), *swiss-cheese polygon* (6 hits), and *non-simply-connected polygon* (1 hit).

Comment: @MTurgeon I think it should be prohibited by definition too, but "plane figure" doesn't seem to exclude holes, nor does "bounded by a closed piecewise linear curve".

Comment: There might be a term based on the fact that these are all the (connected?) planar objects that can be broken up into triangles.

Comment: @rschwieb Maybe I should have phrased it in the following way: "*the* plane figure of 'maximal area' bounded by a closed curve", although this is not quite precise.